# How to let netbeans add parentheses around selected texts?

Tags: java, netbeans, code-assist

I am using netbeans 8.1. I wonder if there is a feature that it add paretheses and quotation around selected text.

Answer (score 0):

like the offciial documentation states>

add this to the code template:

```
("${selection}")${cursor}
```

1. Go to Tools> Options> Editor> Code templates
2. Click New, enter "so" as the abbreviation, then enter the following code as the expanded text:

   ("${selection}")${cursor}
3. In the description tab, enter "Code folding", and click Ok

Comment: Sorry, I think my question is confusing. I mean I want the feature that after I select a code and input parenthesis, it automatically add parenthesis around that code text, instead of replace that selection with a pair of parenthesis. This feature is very heady in Python Jupyter.